# How to make matlab read files with similar file name inside a folder in order?

Tags: matlab

There are several .dat files on which i have to run a matlab function.
Consider four files:

1. text_ph0_1.dat
2. text_ph0_2.dat
3. text_ph0_5.dat
4. text_ph0_10.dat.

**I want the files to be read in the alphabetic order as for each of these files there is a specific argument being passed to the function which is picked from a excel sheet.**

PROBLEM-Following is the code which I have written but MATLAB is not reading the files in order (e.g MATLAB file reading order is 1,4,2,3 following the indexation given in the numbered list above) due to which the arguments associated with each file are being passed incorrectly.

```matlab
filename = 'C:\Book1.xlsx';
freq = xlsread(filename, 'A1:A4');  

myFolder = 'C:\ZynqNew';
% Check to make sure that folder actually exists.
if ~isfolder(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end

% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.dat'); 
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
  baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  maxVal=hppFunction(fullFileName,(1),freq(k),1,1,1,1,1,1);
  arrayPeak(k)=maxVal;
end
```

Can anyone please tell what mistake I am making?

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo ,I haven't tried that.Please let me know how that will help?

Comment: The files are already sorted in the correct order.They are present in the order which i have mentioned in the question.the issue is matlab processing order is 1,4,2,3.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo,I have double checked the filelist. They are in the same order as i have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using leading zeros, the order Matlab uses is the correct alphabetical order (given by the `dir` command). You can use e.g. [`sort_nat`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort_nat-natural-order-sort) from the Matlab File Exchange to fix this issue:

```
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.dat'); 
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
theFilesNatOrder = nat_sort({theFiles.name}); 

for k = 1 : length(theFilesNatOrder)
  baseFileName = theFilesNatOrder{k};

  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
  maxVal=hppFunction(fullFileName,(1),freq(k),1,1,1,1,1,1);
  arrayPeak(k)=maxVal;
end
```

Comment: I think that `(:)` is not necessary in `{theFiles(:).name}`

Comment: @Arthur ah indeed, removed.